# Fix generated image to the center of the browser

Tags: html, css

I am creating an image generating tool. According to the tool,  when a user types his name the image is generated with his/her name.

The problem is that the image appears on the side of the browser window. I want it on the center of the browser. I tried `<img src="path_of_php_file.php">` , but it didn't work .

## My php code

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['imagename'];

if($_POST['imagename'] != ''){



  header("Content-Type: image/png");



$name = $_POST['imagename'];

   $im = @imagecreate(800, 600);

   $background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xDD);

   $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 133, 14, 91);

   imagestring($im, 5, 300, 300,  " Hey $name Whats Up Bro ?", $text_color);



   imagepng($sim);


   imagedestroy($sim);

}

else echo "no image created";
?>
```

## My html code

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="images.php" method="post">

Enter Your Name :<input type="text" name="imagename">

<br></br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

It would be really helpful if you guys tell me how to make my generated image to center. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040554/how-to-put-a-div-in-center-of-browser-using-css

Comment: just understand my question man ....thats not the duplicate of my question

Comment: What do you want to do, to center the image or to center the text in the image?

Comment: to center the image ...

Comment: to the center the random generated image ..

Comment: The fact that the image was generated via php is irrelevant.

Comment: @turboHz so you say i cant add randomly generated php image to center ?

Comment: yeah, place it inside a div that you center using the stackoverflow post I mentioned before, it will be totally centered (you might have to change some css widths and heights)

Comment: @Rsauxil when i add like that what will be my src link ??

Comment: You need to create an image by using imagepng($sim,$location) and then echo html and css to center it (the header can be removed then). Much easier however would be to work with 3 files and instead of using POST to get the text you would use GET. The file you refer to in your src would be something like "image.php?imagename=The+text+you+want" which you could echo like "<img src='image.php?imagename=".urlencode($_POST['imagename'])."'>"

Comment: well ..so what changes i need to make on my code ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on submit, you're returning the image object (without html).

If you want to center that, you'll need to return some html page, add a  tag linking to the image generated, and use some css to center it.

If you don't want to save the image anywhere, you could use a data uri:

http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Comment: i hope this can solve my problem ..but how can i add a php file and a css file to the html form ??

Comment: I'm not going to do it for you, but I can give you some more hints:

Write the html in the PHP file where you're processing the image
and add the CSS inline, inside a <style> tag

Comment: the css and html which you gave me on the link ??