# DOM How to add two divs (with jQuery inside them) next to each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to align my two calendars properly so that my text and my calendars are lined up properly.

I think there are two different ways to approach this: (But I don't know how to do them)

1. Adding the jquery statements inside of the table so that they are properly lined up by the format of the table
2. Fixing the css so that it is formatted properly to the page

This is what it looks like:

[image]

And this is what I want it to look like:

[image]

---

This is my javascript to add the text "Start Date:" and "End Date:" to my table

```js
// to my empty div with the id of roomForDates I create a table to center the text
var holdTheDateInfo = document.getElementById('roomForDates');
var htmlForDateTitles = '<center><table width="400" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">';
htmlForDateTitles += '<tr><td><center> Start Date: </center></td>';
htmlForDateTitles += '<td><center> End Date: </center></td></tr>';
htmlForDateTitles += '</table></center>';
holdTheDateInfo.innerHTML += htmlForDateTitles;
```

This is my jQuery that will add the two calendars to my `div`s named `roomForStartDates` and `roomForEndDates`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Create the Calendar. The navigation is restricted
    // by setting the "min" and "max" dates.
    $("#roomForStartDates").jqxCalendar({
        width: 220,
        min: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
        max: new Date(2014, 11, 31),
        height: 220
    });
    $("#roomForEndDates").jqxCalendar({
        width: 220,
        min: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
        max: new Date(2014, 11, 31),
        height: 220
    });
}); // end document
```

This is my current css that I am having trouble with.

```css
#roomForStartDates {
    float: left;text-align:center;
}
#roomForEndDates {
    float: left;margin-left:50px;text-align:center;
}
```

Thank you in advance!!!! Please let me know if you have any questions!!!

---

Update so far:

[image]

Comment: Why do you have the `width:35%;`s?

Comment: I was trying out different percents to see what would work. I originally tried 50% but that made them even farther apart!

Comment: Get rid of the width fields entirely.

Comment: `float left/right` are complicated things. Why not just put everything in a `<table>`?

Comment: didn't try it out but float left for both and e.g. margin-left:50px; for the right one should fix that (just set the margin-left for the right one until it meets your requirements)

Comment: @Roland I would love to put them into a table (as I said in approach #1) but i just don't know how :(

Comment: @matthias_h What you told helped to put them next to each other, but they still need to be aligned with the text. Is there a way to move the two divs over so that they will line up? P.S. I added a new picture to the bottom of my question so that people can see my problem. Is there a way to center them on the page?

Comment: sure, but I would do it in a proper way; as you know the width of the calendars, you should put the texts in separate divs with the same width; both with float left; sound's complicated but I guess you know where this leads to; to clear the float and get to the next line, you could e.g. add a <div style="clear:left"/> after the 2nd text-div; next "row" contains the divs with the calendars; add for top right text-div the same margin-left as you have for the bottom-right calendar, and this should fix that

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated. Use CSS `text-align: center` instead.

Comment: @Oriol, I used text-align:center; for both of my divs but nothing changed.

Comment: just did a fiddle to illustrate what I meant: http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/owzud4dz/

Comment: @matthias_h I like your fiddle, but when I tried to apply it to my code, it was a mess because I have so many other divs.

Comment: guess so :) was just an example, sorry; should've adjusted it to your current css; but guess if you just have same widths for #roomForStartDates (with the copy, 220px like you have for the calendars), all set to float left, and an extra div with e.g. class "clear" after each two divs and add .clear {clear:left;} it'll be aligned; only thing missing then is the alignment with the line above

Comment: Just updated the fiddle, 2nd version, matching your class names, no clear-element, but an extra container; you would just to have to adjust the widths (container = 2 x width of div - margin(s) )

Comment: There are different ways to get it centered, just one of them in updated Fiddle ;) - http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/owzud4dz/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid too many comments to the general question as this should better be avoided on SO just the mentioned approach as answer. Just adjusted the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/owzud4dz/4/) to this as it's sufficient to have `text-align: center` for the `.container`:

```
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image">__________</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="roomForStartDates">Start Date</div>
    <div id="roomForEndDates">End Date</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jqxCalendar">start calendar</div>
    <div class="jqxCalendar">end calendar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mainContainer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
div.container {
  width: 420px;
  text-align:center;
}
#roomForStartDates, #roomForEndDates, .jqxCalendar {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left:10px;
}

.jqxCalendar {
  height: 200px;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

As it's only an example for demonstration, possible necessary adjustment for your page would be to adjust the width in the .container class. This width should match 2 x calendar-width + the margin(s). As both containers have 200px width and 10px margin-left, it's 420px here. For positioning the whole div centered I've just added another div as wrapper for all containers and used one of different approaches.

In case this won't work for your layout, just have a look at the suggested methods e.g. here:  [Stackoverflow - How to put a div in center of browser using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040554/how-to-put-a-div-in-center-of-browser-using-css)
or leave a comment here in case of issues with this possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would love to put them into a table (as I said in approach #1) but i just don't know how :( –

Here is how to make an HTML table with one row with two data cells (columns). If you use the same layout for both tables, they will appear the same.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    $..... for calendar 1
    </td>
    <td>
    $..... for calendar 2
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have tried to do that by **htmlForDateTitles += '<tr><td><center><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function () {$("#roomForStartDates").jqxCalendar({width: 220,min: new Date(2010, 0, 1),max: new Date(2014, 11, 31),height: 220});});</script></center></td>';** but I haven't had any luck. Do you have any suggestions for me?